# Angular 5 multiple request using single httpclient

Tags: httpclient, angular5, ngrx

I am developing a website using the angular 5. 
The main page display user card list and each user card will be updated at regular intervals.

I implement the UserService that request HTTP request to the server (API server). In the UserListComponent, makes request repeatedly using the userService.

But sometimes some request has not received the response from the server.
In my opinion, this problem is because of the singleton httpclient instance.

```
for(const i in users){
 this.store.dispatch(new UserUpdate(user[i]._id));
}
```

in userEffect, call the UserService and call update function.

```
  @Effect() UserUpdateAction = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActions.USER_UPDATE)
    .switchMap((action: UserActions.UserUpdate) => {
       return this.userService.get(action.id)
        .map(res => {
          if (res.code === RESPONSE_CODE.SUCCESS) {
             return new UserAcions.UserUpdateSuccess(res.data));                
          } else {
             return {type: 'NO_ACTION'}              
          }
        });
    });
```

[image]

Above image describe my issue. I can see all response from the server. But browser cannot recognize the first request.

Comment: you are using ngrx  ?

Comment: @Vega yes our projcect is based on redux ( ngrx )

Comment: I guess ngrx-store too? if so, your post needs to have these tags too to have more visibility and help :)

Comment: @Vega i think this problem is not related to ngrx-store. in the browser dev-tool`s network tab, response is not valid.

Comment: @Vega if you have any idea of this problem, comment me that what kind of information you need!!

Comment: I'd bet that you have in-flight requests that are getting canceled because you are using `switchMap` rather than `mergeMap` in your effect.

Comment: @bygrace thank you! It is working correctly after changing switchMap to mergeMap.